# How do I write a formula to convert a string data ("yyyy.mm.dd) to a common date format (mm/dd/yyyy)?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have a data value in column "A" that contains a date formatted as "yyyy.mm.dd", such as...

```
2015.01.30
2015.02.06
2015.12.31
```

I'd like to write a function, in column "B", that converts the dates in column "A" to the following formats (mm/dd/yyyy), such as...

```
1/30/2015
2/06/2015
12/31/2015
```

**My question:** How do I write a formula in column "B" that looks for a string in column "A" (formatted as yyyy.mm.dd) and converts it to a new format ("mm/dd/yyyy")?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: maybe interesting? [Convert Date from yyyymmdd to mm/dd/yyyy Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056051/convert-date-from-yyyymmdd-to-mm-dd-yyyy-excel). It may be worth looking at the _Related_ links on the right-hand-side of that page?

Comment: I already did.  That example uses a fixed position assumption for identifying yyyy, mm, and dd.  It does not look for a token separator like "." which is used as a separator.

Comment: Ok, then it would help us if you mentioned that in your question? i.e. Your question repeats about fixed format input - a lot. No mention _anywhere_ about using '.' as a token separator. Please update your question about using '.' as a token separator for variable length days and month strings. It will make it clear what you really want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/"),"m/dd/yyyy")
```

or:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/"))
```

and Format `m/dd/yyyy`

Comment: The TEXT formula is simple enough.  The DATEVALUE is not so clear.

Comment: TEXT returns a text value, DATEVALUE returns an integer that represents the date in excel format which then allows it to be manipulated much easier usually or used in other formulas.