# Date function in excel?

Tags: excel, function, date

I have an excel file that a column with a date. the date is structured like this:20160711. I want the date to look like this: 07/11/2016 any easy way to do this?

Comment: text-to-columns, fixed width, date:ymd, finish then format the cell as mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: You can use the formula that you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13056198/1008588

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

From memory back in the Window's Days...

Select the Cells you want to format...

Right click >> Format Cells >> date

Select whatever format you like.

Comment: it's not working. Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific...

Comment: so I have a column with probably 200 dates. the date is structured like this:  20160711 where yearmonthday. i want the date to look like month/day/month. i tried the format way and it's giving me bunch of error ######

Comment: This will not work as Excel see it as a number and not a date.  The number is too large for a standard date.